# que debo hacer para que me muestre el numero correcto y no formulado

Tags: excel, formato

Tengo una celda formulada con un SI y el resultado debe es un numero, ya fui a formato de la celda y seleccione formato numero.

ahora desde word estoy tratando de imprimir en un formulario pre impreso, asi que escanee el formulario lo importe en word y allí le asigno los campos de excel por medio de correspondencia, me trae los campos bn sin embargo no me muestra el numero como debería ser si no que me muestra algo asi 112234566+E1

que debo hacer para que me muestre el numero correcto y no formulado.

ya intente colocar en el excel la casilla en formato texto pero no funciona.

Comment: Relacionado http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25506/forzar-n%C3%BAmeros-a-texto-en-excel

Answer (score 1):

En la celda de la fórmula debo presionar <kbd>F9</kbd> y automáticamente convierte la fórmula en un valor.