# Forzar números a texto en Excel

Tags: excel, asp, csv, formulas

Estoy haciendo una exportación de datos a un `.csv` a través de un `asp`.

Hay algunos datos que tienen 0's a la izquierda. Por ejemplo: `005`.

Para evitar que Excel me lo convierta a numero y desaparezcan los 0's, hago lo siguiente:

```
campo = "=" & chr(34) & campo & chr(34)
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Mi problema viene cuando abro Excel y lo guardo. Al volver a abrirlo se me convierte automáticamente a número y me desaparecen los 0's.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

¿Sabe alguien alguna otra forma de forzar los valores a texto?

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba a poner una comilla simple delante del número al hacer la exportación (algo así: '005 ). Se me ocurre que puede funcionar ya que excel (y openoffice) usan la comilla simple internamente para poner números cómo texto.

Answer (score 4):

en excel tenes 2 opciones para que un numero sea Texto:

Opcion 1: como dijo luis, con una comilla la principio.

[image: Opcion1]

Opcion 2: A travez d la formula "=Texto(valor;formato)"

[image: opcion2]

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas

1. Usar formato personalizado
2. Usar la función TEXTO
3. Usar un apóstrofe

Los detalles en el artículo oficial de Excel, [Mantener los ceros a la izquierda](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Mantener-los-ceros-a-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7)

Answer (score 0):

Si requieres definir una cadena de código variable también puedes definir un **"n"** con el valor deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Empleando la siguiente fórmula , dónde **`n`** en este caso lo definí con valor `5`:

```
=REPETIR("0";n-LARGO(A4))&A4
```

Y obtendrías lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O empleando la fórmula `Texto` que ha sido mencionada en una respuesta previa:

```
=TEXTO(A4;REPETIR("0";n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Querer mantener ceros a la izquierda implica también la necesidad de formatear. En tu caso veo que el número maximo de digitos es de tres. Bueno, pues basta con formatear la celda con tres ceros **000**. Si quieres más ceros los añades sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de que quieras mantener los ceros cuando borras la celda puedes hacer dos cosas. Cambiar la configuración avanzada de Excel o incluir unas líneas de codigo que refresquen la celda eliminada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer sin meter mano al Excel ya que su configuración depende la maquina del usuario que habrá el archivo.

Que librería estas usando para generar el Excel? Por ejemplo en ClosedXML puedes definir el tipo de dato de la celda como texto por lo que si pones "009" lo va a tomar como un string y no va a eliminar los ceros de la izquierda al abrirse.

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Data-Types